# ¿consultas en tablas relacionadas MySql?

Tags: mysql

Con esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM dtnombrepresencia where cod_fknombre_plantas=1;
```

Obtengo:

```
+--------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| cod_dt | fecha_registro | cod_fknombre_plantas | cod_nombre_entidades | tamano_muestra | cantidad_td | promedio_viaje_td |
+--------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1 | 2019-12-29 | 1 | 2 | 100 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 2019-12-29 | 1 | 3 | 100 | 10 | 10 |
| 7 | 2019-12-29 | 1 | 2 | 100 | 20 | 20 |
+--------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Pero me gustaría visualizar:

```
+--------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| cod_dt | fecha_registro | nombre_plantas | nombre_p | tamano_muestra | cantidad_td | promedio_viaje_td |
+--------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1 | 2019-12-29 |RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO |PRESENCIA DE MUSLOS FRACTURADOS | 100 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 2019-12-29 |RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO |PRESENCIA DE PIEL RASGADA | 100 | 10 | 10 |
| 7 | 2019-12-29 |RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO |PRESENCIA DE MUSLOS FRACTURADOS | 100 | 20 | 20 |
+--------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Es decir, que se sustituyan los códigos de plantas y entidades por lo que representan.

Lo he intentado con:

```
SELECT * FROM dtnombrepresencia JOIN nombreplantas
  where nombre_planta LIKE '%RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO%';
```

Pero no consigo que funcione.

Aporto el dataset en MySQL:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.2
-- phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 29-12-2019 a las 15:18:24
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.10-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.3.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `pruebas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `contador_fecha`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `contador_fecha` (
`fecha` date
,`total_repetidas` bigint(21)
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--

CREATE TABLE `dtnombrepresencia` (
`cod_dt` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha_registro` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`cod_fknombre_plantas` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cod_nombre_entidades` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tamano_muestra` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cantidad_td` int(11) NOT NULL,
`promedio_viaje_td` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--

INSERT INTO `dtnombrepresencia` (`cod_dt`, `fecha_registro`, `cod_fknombre_plantas`, `cod_nombre_entidades`, `tamano_muestra`, `cantidad_td`, `promedio_viaje_td`) VALUES
(1, '2019-12-29', 1, 2, 100, 10, 10),
(2, '2019-12-29', 2, 3, 100, 10, 10),
(3, '2019-12-29', 1, 3, 100, 10, 10),
(4, '2019-12-29', 2, 1, 90, 25, 27.78),
(5, '2019-12-29', 3, 2, 38, 25, 65.79),
(6, '2019-12-29', 3, 2, 38, 25, 65.79),
(7, '2019-12-29', 1, 2, 100, 20, 20),
(8, '2019-12-29', 2, 1, 100, 10, 10),
(9, '2019-12-29', 2, 1, 100, 10, 10);

--
-- Disparadores `dtnombrepresencia`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `dtnombrepresencia_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `dtnombrepresencia` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.promedio_viaje_td=FORMAT(NEW.cantidad_td*100/NEW.tamano_muestra,2)
$$
DELIMITER ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `dtnombrepresencia_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `dtnombrepresencia` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.promedio_viaje_td=FORMAT(NEW.cantidad_td*100/NEW.tamano_muestra,2)
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `fecha`
--

CREATE TABLE `fecha` (
`id_fecha` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fechas` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`hora` time NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`asistentes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `fecha`
--

INSERT INTO `fecha` (`id_fecha`, `fechas`, `hora`, `asistentes`) VALUES
(1, '2019-12-29', '11:13:27', 0),
(2, '2019-12-29', '12:18:21', 0),
(3, '2019-12-29', '02:18:27', 0);

--
-- Disparadores `fecha`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `fecha_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `fecha` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.hora=TIME_FORMAT(new.hora, "%r")
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `fecha_detalle`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `fecha_detalle` (
`fecha` date
,`fechas_repetidas` bigint(21)
,`total_asisten_por_fecha` decimal(32,0)
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `nombreplantas`
--

CREATE TABLE `nombreplantas` (
`cod_nombre_planta` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre_planta` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `nombreplantas`
--

INSERT INTO `nombreplantas` (`cod_nombre_planta`, `nombre_planta`) VALUES
(1, 'RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO'),
(2, 'ENTRADA DE LA PELADORA'),
(3, 'SALIDA DE LA PELADORA');

--
-- Disparadores `nombreplantas`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `nombreplantas_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `nombreplantas` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @nombreplantass =(SELECT COUNT(nombreplantas.nombre_plantas)
FROM nombreplantas WHERE nombreplantas.nombre_plantas = NEW.nombre_plantas);
IF @nombreplantass > 0 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NO SE PUEDE REGISTRAR, YA SE ENCUENTRA EN LA BD';
END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--

CREATE TABLE `nombres_entidades` (
`cod_entidad_presencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre_ep` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--

INSERT INTO `nombres_entidades` (`cod_entidad_presencia`, `nombre_ep`) VALUES
(1, 'PRESENCIA DE ALAS FRACTURADAS'),
(2, 'PRESENCIA DE MUSLOS FRACTURADOS'),
(3, 'PRESENCIA DE PIEL RASGADA');

--
-- Disparadores `nombres_entidades`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `nombreentidades_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `nombres_entidades` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @nombreentidades =(SELECT COUNT(nombres_entidades.nombre_ep)
FROM nombres_entidades WHERE nombres_entidades.nombre_ep = NEW.nombre_ep);
IF @nombreentidades > 0 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NO SE PUEDE REGISTRAR, YA SE ENCUENTRA EN LA BD';
END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `contador_fecha`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contador_fecha`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `contador_fecha` AS select `fecha`.`fechas` AS `fecha`,count(`fecha`.`fechas`) AS `total_repetidas` from `fecha` group by `fecha`.`fechas` having count(0) > 0 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `fecha_detalle`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fecha_detalle`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `fecha_detalle` AS select `fecha`.`fechas` AS `fecha`,count(`fecha`.`fechas`) AS `fechas_repetidas`,sum(`fecha`.`asistentes`) AS `total_asisten_por_fecha` from `fecha` group by `fecha`.`fechas` order by `fecha`.`fechas` ;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `dtnombrepresencia`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_dt`),
ADD KEY `cod_nombre_entidades` (`cod_nombre_entidades`),
ADD KEY `cod_fknombre_plantas` (`cod_fknombre_plantas`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `fecha`
--
ALTER TABLE `fecha`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_fecha`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `nombreplantas`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombreplantas`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_nombre_planta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombres_entidades`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_entidad_presencia`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `dtnombrepresencia`
MODIFY `cod_dt` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `fecha`
--
ALTER TABLE `fecha`
MODIFY `id_fecha` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `nombreplantas`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombreplantas`
MODIFY `cod_nombre_planta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `nombres_entidades`
--
ALTER TABLE `nombres_entidades`
MODIFY `cod_entidad_presencia` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `dtnombrepresencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `dtnombrepresencia`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_dtnombrepresencia_nombreplantas` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_fknombre_plantas`) REFERENCES `nombreplantas` (`cod_nombre_planta`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_dtnombrepresencia_nombres_entidades` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_nombre_entidades`) REFERENCES `nombres_entidades` (`cod_entidad_presencia`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: yo no veo ni un solo join en ninguna de tus consultas...

Comment: ah olvide subir la el otro select, ya lo edito.

Comment: esta en una delas imagenes en la ultima

Comment: las imagenes son dificiles de ver.. e igual, ese join esta mal escrito, sobre que columnas tiene que unir las tablas? le falta ese dato...

Comment: las columna son las que tienen la llave de color verde son las llaves foreaneas a las otras dos tablas

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir, las imagenes son dificiles de ver. E igual, ese join esta incompleto. La clausuale es Join tabla ON campo1 = campo2, si no, la db no sabe como unir las dos tablas. No importa que tenga llaves o no, el query necesita saber como unirlas

Comment: no.. es 1 a n... @Aprendiz

Comment: Dices que ... *siempre he tenido problemas con consultas con join* ...  Las consultas con `JOIN` son mucho más claras que con `WHERE` por ejemplo, es cuestión de aprender a escribirlas. Como ya dijo @gbianchi te falta la parte del `JOIN ON unaTabla.unaColumna=otraTabla.otraColumna` donde se indica por qué columna se unen los datos en las tablas.

Comment: ok, entiendo, es decir que agregando en on obtendria el resutado que deseo.

Comment: Uno o varios, dependiendo de cuántas tablas intervengan en la relación. Aparte de lanzarnos el dataset sin más, dinos qué tablas intervienen en esos resultados que esperas y por qué columnas se relacionan. Esa es precusamente la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: bueno habia publicado toda la informacion, pero la editaron. ya que tambien estaba preguntando como hacer consultas en tablas no relacionadas, pero editaron mi otra informacion.

Comment: @CRIS19N, en la respuesta de abajo intento explicar la diferencia entre relación y combinación, que parece que es lo que te confunde. Ya me dices...

Comment: si ya voy entiendo, voy a praticar con otras consultas, gracias.

Comment: SELECT fecha FROM promedio_total JOIN dtnombrepresencia
 ON fecha_registro=fecha
  WHERE fecha<>fecha_registro;   aqui uni la fecha de una tabla  y con la cláusula where quiero obtener las fecha que son diferentes a fecha_registro, pero el resultado es 0, y tengo una sola fecha que no esta en el campo fecha_registro. ¿el join y on tambien funciona para tablas no relacionadas?

Comment: @CRIS19N en el dataset de esta pregunta no figura la tabla `promedio_total`, entiendo que deberías abrir una nueva pregunta en el que aportes el nuevo dataset y esta nueva cuestión para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: @CRIS19N la pregunta la editaste vos? fue editada con tu permiso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te indican los compañeros, la consulta que estás buscando sería:

```
SELECT cod_dt,fecha_registro,nombre_planta,
  nombre_ep,tamano_muestra,cantidad_td,promedio_viaje_td
  FROM dtnombrepresencia
  JOIN nombreplantas JOIN nombres_entidades
  ON cod_nombre_planta=cod_fknombre_plantas
  AND cod_nombre_entidades=cod_entidad_presencia;
```

Con respecto al JOIN y respondiendo a tus comentarios:

- No es necesario que las tablas estén *relacionadas* para *combinarlas*
- Las tablas se relacionan con claves ajenas para evitar datos inconsistentes. Es decir, para evitar que, en `dtnombrepresencia` metas el código de una planta que aún no has registrado en `nombreplantas` .
- En cambio, combinas tablas para conectarlas por datos coincidentes en ambas tablas. O sea, para que hagas coincidir cada código de planta en `dtnombrepresencia` con el resto de datos de cada planta en `nombreplantas` haciendo uso de su código.

Para entender cómo funciona `JOIN` es mejor empezar con uno sencillo, entenderlo con uno doble es un mordisco un poco grande. Pero al menos ya sabes por dónde empezar a estudiarlo.

Tras el `JOIN` puedes hacer perfectamente un `WHERE` para quedarte con los registros que te interesen. Incluso podrías aplicar la lógica en el mismo `ON` (si sustiyes el `WHERE` por `AND` verás que funciona igual). Haciendo pruebas con consultas pequeñas se ve muy bien.

```
SELECT cod_dt,fecha_registro,nombre_planta,
  nombre_ep,tamano_muestra,cantidad_td,promedio_viaje_td
  FROM dtnombrepresencia
  JOIN nombreplantas JOIN nombres_entidades
  ON cod_nombre_planta=cod_fknombre_plantas
  AND cod_nombre_entidades=cod_entidad_presencia
  WHERE nombre_planta='RECEPCION Y SACRIFICIO';
```

Por favor, escribe en los comentarios las dudas que te surjan al revisarlo.

Comment: Explica un poco en qué consiste, el OP ha dicho que no entiende los `JOIN`. Si lo explicas ya sabrá cómo hacer en futuras consultas parecidas.

Comment: Dadme un momento, ahora mismo la amplío, ¡gracias!

Comment: Que forma rara de escribir un join.. igual creo que de su pregunta original a esta hay un abismo (no es tu culpa) y esta ultima, casi que deberia resolverse sin joins, con subselects funcionaria igual y seria mas facil de ver...

Comment: una preguta y si queiro hacer una consulta con la clausula where en dos tablas no relacionadas, podria aplicar el join, o como seria.

Comment: Ok, a ver si así se entiende algo mejor... ya me decís, gracias por vuestras aportaciones :)

Comment: @CRIS19N he ampliado la respuesta para incluir lo que comentas sobre el ´WHERE´

Comment: osea lo que entiendo repecto al join es que tambien se puede unir con este dos tablas no relacionadas, y que con el on podria aplicar la condicion(fecha<>fecha_registro) o solo es para unir los campos a comparar, y luego con la clausula where puedo hacer la condicion?

Comment: @CRIS19N Lo que hace un join es por cada fila que toma de una tabla, busca segun la condicion de join (lo que pusiste en el ON) todas aquellas filas de la otra tabla que cumplan la misma. Si haces una condicion por fecha distinta, va a traer muchisimos mas registros de los que buscas de seguro. Tene en cuenta que el join es 1 fila de origen, toda la tabla de destino, por cada fila de origen. De la tabla de destino, siempre busca en todos los registros si cumplen la condicion o no.